# CUFFT output not aligned the same as FFTW output

Tags: c++, cuda, fft, fftw

I am doing a 1D FFT. I have the same input data as would go in FFTW, however, the return from CUFFT does not seem to be "aligned" the same was FFTW is. That is, In my FFTW code, I could calculate the center of the zero padding, then do some shifting to "left-align" all my data, and have trailing zeros.

In CUFFT, the result from the FFT is data that looks like it is the same, however, the zeros are not "centered" in the output, so the rest of my algorithm breaks. (The shifting to left-align the data still has a "gap" in it after the bad shift).

Can anyone give me any insight? I thought it had something to do with those compatibility flags, but even with      cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_FFTW_ALL); I am still getting a bad result.

Below is a plot of the magnitude of the data from the first row. The data on the left is the output of the inverse CUFFT, and the output on the right is the output of the inverse FFTW.

Thanks![image]

Here is the setup code for the FFTW and CUFFT plans

```
ifft = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(freqCols, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(indata), 

                  reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(outdata), 

                  FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

CUFFT:

```
cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_FFTW_ALL);
cufftPlan1d(&plan, width, CUFFT_C2C, height);
```

and executing code:

```
fftwf_execute(ifft);
```

CUFFT:

```
cufftExecC2C(plan, d_image, d_image, CUFFT_INVERSE); //in place inverse
```

Completed some test code:

```
complex<float> *input = (complex<float>*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * 100);
    complex<float> *output = (complex<float>*)fftwf_malloc(sizeof(fftwf_complex) * 100);

    fftwf_plan ifft;
    ifft = fftwf_plan_dft_1d(100, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(input), 

                          reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(output), 

                          FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);


    cufftComplex *inplace = (cufftComplex *)malloc(100*sizeof(cufftComplex));
    cufftComplex *d_inplace;
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_inplace,100*sizeof(cufftComplex));
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        inplace[i] = make_cuComplex(cos(.5*M_PI*i),sin(.5*M_PI*i));
        input[i] = complex<float>(cos(.5*M_PI*i),sin(.5*M_PI*i));
    }

    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(d_inplace, inplace, 100*sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftPlan1d(&plan, 100, CUFFT_C2C, 1);
    cufftExecC2C(plan, d_inplace, d_inplace, CUFFT_INVERSE);
    cutilSafeCall(cudaMemcpy(inplace, d_inplace, 100*sizeof(cufftComplex), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));


    fftwf_execute(ifft);
```

When I dumped the output from both of these FFT calls, it did look the same. I am not exactly sure what I was looking at though. The data had a value of 100 in the 75th row. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you post some of the data from each, e.g. for the first few bins ?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the resulting magnitude plot of the first row, which illustrates what I am talking about

Comment: Are you doing a forward FFT prior to this inverse FFT or did you start out in the frequency domain ? Does the frequency domain data match ?

Comment: The data starts out as complex data. They do match exactly, in both the FFTW and CUFFT versions

Comment: OK - is this a complex-to-real IFFT or complex-to-complex ? You might want to double check how both FFTW and CUFFT expect the frequency domain data to be ordered, particularly the 0 and N/2 bins. It looks like you just have a shift in the time domain result but I can't quite guess how this might be happening...

Comment: Oh sorry - it's complex to complex. Added the setup code for my plans for both. The CUFFT is actually a batch, to do height FFTs of width. the fftw code simple calls ifft in a loop over the rows. The output data I plotted is from the zero'th row of each

Comment: It looks like you might have *inverse* FFT for FFTW but *forward* FFT for CUFFT ? (Or maybe not - looks like CUFFT lets you specify direction when you execute the FFT ?)

Comment: I added the execution snips. The CUFFT_INVERSE is specified. Do you know where to find the ordering info for each of these? I did find http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_2.html#SEC3 that says that the FFTW forward DFT stores DC in out[0]. Maybe I need to do a shift of my data first in the CUFFT version to swap the halves of the original input row before doing the rest of the operations?

Comment: Although I'm fairly familiar with FFTW, and also with CUDA in general, I haven't actually used CUFFT. I would suggest as an experiment doing a *forward* FFT with both FFTW and CUFFT using a well-defined input signal and then compare the FFT outputs - that may help to determine any difference in the ordering of frequency domain bins (assuming this information can't be gleaned from the documentation).

Comment: Added some explicit code to generate the same IFFT in FFTW and CUFFT. Can you check it out?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you may have swapped the real and imaginary components of your complex data in the input to one of the IFFTs.  This swap will change an even function to an odd function in the time domain.

Comment: I dont think this is possible is it? That seems like something that would have to be done purposefully, and I already checked immediately before the IFFT was calculated, that both versions plot the same

Comment: Added more sample code - with an explicit signal. Can you check it out?

Comment: I've just been reading the CUFFT documentation and I have to admit I'm stumped. What version of the CUDA SDK and toolkit are you using ? One minor point is that it looks like you don't need FFTW compatibility mode - this is just for R-to-C and C-to-R transforms in 2 or more dimensions.

Comment: It is CUDA 4.0 - and yeah< i didnt think I needed compatibility mode, I was just stumped as to what else to try

Comment: @hotpaw2 i think you may be on to something. I have just plotted some of my original input and for some reason it seems as though the R and I parts are swapped, which is why it was not obvious in the magnitude plot, because it came out the same